# Lovasz theta function and regular graphs (odd cycles in particular) - connections to spectral theory

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory

The post is related to:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59631/lovasz-theta-function-and-independence-number-of-product-of-simple-odd-cycles

How far away is the Lovasz bound from the zero-error capacity of regular graphs? Are there any examples where the Lovasz bound is known to be not equal to the zero-error capacity of a regular graph? (This was answered below by Oleksandr Bondarenko.)

In particular is any strict inequality known for odd cycles of sides greater than or equal to $7$?

**Update**
What improvement is needed in spectral theory to improve the Lovasz theta function so that the gap between Shannon capacity and Lovasz Theta for the cases for which a gap exists could be lowered? (Note I am concerned only from spectral perspective)

Comment: I've delete my wrong answer. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I do not understand the update, if there is a gap between zero-error capacity and $\vartheta$, how can you "lower" it?

Comment: I thing the phrasing is bad. Say $\delta=\vartheta-\Theta$ is the capacity gap between $\vartheta$ and $\Theta$. If some improvement could be made to spectral theory technology so that the new technique yields a sharper upper bound as compared to $\vartheta$ when $\delta>0$, what could that possible improvemnt be in spectral theory technology? Basically the update asks if spectral theory as of today faces such blocks to improvement.

Answer (score 13):

In fact there is known a regular graph $G$ for which zero-error capacity  $\Theta(G)$ is less than the Lov$\acute{a}$sz bound $\vartheta(G)$. W. Haemers in $[1]$ has proved that for the complement of [Schl$\ddot{a}$fli graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_graph) $G$ the following holds: $\Theta(G)\leqslant7<\vartheta(G)=9$.

In $[2]$ it is noted that "The best known upper bounds on $\Theta(C_m)$ and $\Theta(\overline{C}_m)$ for $m$ odd and greater than $5$ are given by the Lovasz theta function ...". From this I conclude that that the answer to your last question is no (since then I don't know any results improving on this.).

Finding Shannon capacity even for $C_7$ would be a major breakthrough for this hard problem. Additionally, it can be noticed that

> "it is not known if the problem of deciding whether the Shannon capacity of a given input graph exceeds a given value is decidable".

1. W. Haemers, “[On some problems of Lov$\acute{a}$sz concerning the Shannon capacity of a graph](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1056027),” IEEE Trans. on Information Theory, vol. 25, no. 2, pp. 231–232, Mar. 1979.
2. T. Bohman, "[A limit theorem for the Shannon capacities of odd cycles. II](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-02/S0002-9939-04-07470-2/S0002-9939-04-07470-2.pdf)," Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 2005.
3. N. Alon, "[Combinatorial Reasoning in Information Theory](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Combinatorial%20Reasoning%20in%20Information%20Theory%22&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,5)".

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the same known for simple odd cycles? For example $7$-sided polygon?

Comment: SO it is not known. This is very interesting.